# "Not a whole File" Exception when trying to get ParcelFileDescriptor from Uri

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I have an activity that can receive intents with ACTION_VIEW, and "application/octet-stream" mime types.
when I receive a file from "Google Drive" android app, Uri is in Intent Extra's getParcelableExtra() and every thing works fine.

```
Uri returnUri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
if (returnUri == null)
    returnUri = getIntent().getData();
ParcelFileDescriptor mInputPFD;
try {
// Get the content resolver instance for this context, and use
// it to get a ParcelFileDescriptor for the file.
   mInputPFD = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r"); //Line:87 (Exception here)
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
     Log.e("MainActivity", "File not found.");
     return false;
}
// Get a regular file descriptor for the file
FileDescriptor fd = mInputPFD.getFileDescriptor();
```

But when I receive an Intent from "OneDrive" android app, Uri is in getData() and when I try to obtain a ParcelFileDescriptor from Uri, I receive an exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Not a whole file

at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:542)
at <one of my classes>(<class name>.java:87)
```

**EDIT:**
I am choosing same files for both Google Drive and OneDrive

Comment: What is the OS version of your device that u are testing both ?

Comment: Have you add necessary permission to ur manifest file?

Comment: OS version: android 4.1.2

Comment: I am receiving the Intent, why should I need permissions?

Comment: What are you try to fetch?

Comment: A file with unknown extention from OneDrive

Comment: Did you ever find the solution?